# How to add views in viewgroup(Linear Layout) at run time in Appwidget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am trying to add a view at runtime in my linear layout in widget.

Below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/widget_image"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:text="Test" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/widget_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/widget_text"

    tools:text="Refresh" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_results_row_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/widget_action_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i want to add a textview to this linear layout.

```
//My main layout containing the linearlayout(ll_results_row_container).

RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.simple_widget);

RemoteViews rmView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.id.ll_results_row_container);

for(int i=0li<3i++){
rmView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_data, "Testing");
// layout_row_results is my layout of textview

remoteViews.addView(R.layout.layout_row_results, rmView);
}
```

i am not getting the view on widget. Please help.

Comment: Do you call 'appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId,remoteViews);' after view has been added to RemoteViews?

Comment: Yes. i am calling the method to update the widgets.